# Printing Multiple URLs from a Notepad

Tags: excel, vba

I have many urls in a Excel File. I am trying to Open Each URL and Print/Save the Page as PDF in silent mode.  I have the below code. This works but asking for Print confirmation (Print Dialogue Window). Can anyone has idea to print in silent mode i.e. without showing print dialogue window.

```
Sub View_Tech_Recalls()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   Recall_URL = Range("A1").Value
    ie.Navigate Recall_URL
    ie.StatusBar = False
    ie.Toolbar = True
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Resizable = True
    ie.AddressBar = False


    TimeOutWebQuery = 5
    TimeOutTime = DateAdd("s", TimeOutWebQuery, Now)
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
        If Now > TimeOutTime Then
            ie.stop
            GoTo ErrorTimeOut
        End If
    Loop




    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    ie.ExecWB 6, 2

ErrorTimeOut:


    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on implementation for your requirements, but maybe `ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF` might be your solution?

Then you can set `application.displayalerts = false` prior execution, so should go rather silently.